# Bitwise operation on unsigned char

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I have a sample function as below:

```
int get_hash (unsigned char* str)
{
    int hash = (str[3]^str[4]^str[5]) % MAX;
    int hashVal =  arr[hash];
    return hashVal;
}
```

Here array arr has size as MAX. ( `int arr[MAX]` ).

My static code checker complains that there can be a out of bound array access here, as hash could be in the range -255 to -1.

Is this correct? Can bitwise operation on unsigned char produce a negative number? Should hash be declared as unsigned int?

Comment: When used with arithmetic/bitwise operations, an `unsigned char` is implicitly converted to `int` (yes, **signed** int) before the computation. (Now, a XOR between two ints in the range [0,255] will always yield an int in the same range (thus, never negative), but the static checker can't be that "deep".)

Comment: Assuming an int is bigger than a char on your platform, this code looks fine.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Oh, good point. Correction to my previous comment: on a platform where both `unsigned char` and `int` are the same size (say, 32 bits), then an `unsigned char` would be implicitly converted to `unsigned int` (the "unsignedness" would be preserved, because converting to signed `int` could potentially yield a different (negative) value).

Comment: @gx_ However the code assigns the result of the modulus operator to a signed `int`, so (depending on the value of `MAX` which we have not been given) it may be possible to produce a negative array index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this correct?

No, the static code checker is in error<sup>(1)</sup>.

> Can bitwise operation on unsigned char produce a negative number?

Some bitwise operations can - bitwise complement, for example - but not the exclusive or.

For the `^`, the arguments, `unsigned char` here, are subject to the usual arithmetic conversions (6.3.1.8), they are first promoted according to the integer promotions; about those, clause 6.3.1.1, paragraph 2 says

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the integer promotions.

So, there are two possibilities:

1. An `int` can represent all possible values of `unsigned char`. Then all values obtained from the integer promotions are non-negative, the bitwise exclusive or of these values is also non-negative, and the remainder modulo `MAX` too. The value of `hash` is then in the range from 0 (inclusive) to `MAX` (exclusive) [`-MAX` if `MAX < 0`].
2. An `int` cannot represent all possible values of `unsigned char`. Then the values are promoted to type `unsigned int`, and the bitwise operations are carried out at that type. The result is of course non-negative, and the remainder modulo `MAX` will be non-negative too. However, in that case, the assignment to `int hash` might convert an out-of-range value to a negative value [the conversion of out-of-range integers to a signed integer type is implementation-defined]. <sup>(1)</sup>But in that case, the range of possible negative values is greater than `-255` to `-1`, so even in that - very unlikely - case, the static code checker is wrong in part.

> Should hash be declared as `unsigned int`?

That depends on the value of `MAX`. If there is the slightest possibility that a remainder modulo `MAX` is out-of-range for `int`, then that would be safer. Otherwise, `int` is equally safe.

Comment: There's no downside to making the index an `unsigned int`, so I would recommend doing that anyway, just to avoid any esoteric possibilities

Answer (score 1):

As remarked correctly by gx_, the arithmetic is done in `int`. Just declare your `hash` variable as `unsigned char`, again, to be sure that everybody knows that you expect this to be  positive in all cases.

And if `MAX` is effectively `UCHAR_MAX` you should just use that to improve readability.

Comment: But even if `hash` is unsigned, note that `str[3]`, `str[4]` and `str[5]` respectively are implicitly promoted to the type `int` and the XOR is therefore performed on signed ints. In the end, `unsigned int hash` will solve that problem, but ideally the whole expression would be written as `unsigned int hash = ((unsigned int)str[3]^str[4]^str[5]) % MAX;`.

Comment: @Lundin, no I think that forcing `hash` to be of `unsigned char`, not `unsigned int` should convince the static analyser about the possible range of `hash`. Any value that the expression on the rhs would have, would be converted to the correct range `0...UCHAR_MAX`.